# Drop down does not come down by clicking on the

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is how I "rents" with boostrap with sass and this is how when I click on my drop down menu which I add to the menu so it will not "come" down in other words showcase itself.

I have done so here at the menu.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">Opret <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

at the bottom of the page, I add the new version of jquery and the old version which comes with the package when I collect Bootstrap to my visual studio Express 2013

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="../javascripts/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

```
<script src="../javascripts/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Instruktor Panel</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="../stylesheets/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../stylesheets/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

**EDIT 3 - Problem I found located here:**

```
<script src="../javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It was me who had written that it was in js but it is all in javascript

Comment: do you see any js error from the console?

Comment: do you have your own stylesheet(css) to modify the bootstrap?

Comment: @JeanGkol I add how the head looks at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions jquery js file. Remove one of them, and then try again.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I just copied your html code and added jquery and bootstrap js files. It works in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/zujsgo4e/)**

Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by User86745458</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="true">Opret <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried to take one of them away and it also does not work

Comment: I add up the code, how I have done it in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Nor will there be nothing there at all. It will also not do anything if I do browser for mobile friendly. :/

Comment: I hope you will give me a +1 for good issues, while the team you update about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Other javascript plugins or your own javascript is recommended to be placed on the `<head>`

```
<head>
      <script src="../javascripts/js/lightbox.js"></script>
</head>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can see what's wrong/missing on the 'console' section of the browser.
Press F12 or right click on the page then click 'inspect element' then find 'console'.

Comment: it says that there are no errors whatsoever to seek jquery all.

Comment: it seems that lightbox.js needs the jquery above it

Comment: @JeanGkol No, that was not it.